# Excel VBA range.calculate - bug?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I'm writing a little unit test for a template I'm doing. To optimize the testing, I'm setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

As I want to retrieve the calculated values for each test row, I'm using `theRange.Calculate` to obtain the value of the cell.

This fails to update the value.

I've tried using `sheet.Calculate` with the exact same result.

After finishing, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` updates all values.

After reading the [documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) I'm starting to think this is a bug.

The formula I want to have calculated uses named ranges could that affect the calculation? The formula is inside a table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't calculate only one sheet without the others. You could try set value to cells by macro, but I don't think you'll be satisfied.